# How do I make a random number generate into a textbox instead of just on the page?

Tags: javascript, html

I need the random number I am generating to populate the textbox instead of directly on the page.

```
<input type="text" name="numberbox" value="" size="17" maxlength="10" required>
 <button type=button onclick="document.getElementById('number').innerHTML = getRndInteger(10000,99999)">Number Generator</button>

<p id="number"></p>

<script>
function getRndInteger(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}
const rndInt = randomIntFromInterval(1, 6)
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You are encouraged to make an attempt to write your code.  If you encounter a specific technical problem during that attempt, such as an error or unexpected result, we can help with that.  Please provide specific information about that attempt and what didn't work as expected.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Note: you don't have a function called `randomIntFromInterval`.

Comment: Basically... What happens when you use your favorite search engine to look up how to set the value of a text input in JavaScript?  What happens when you try to apply that knowledge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the random number generate into a textbox, you need to modify the `onclick` function of the button. Instead of setting the generated random number directly to the `innerHTML` of the `<p>` element, you can set it as the value of the text input box.

```js
function generateRandomNumber() {
  const randomNumber = getRndInteger(10000, 99999);
  document.getElementById('numberbox').value = randomNumber;
}

function getRndInteger(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="numberbox" id="numberbox" value="" size="17" maxlength="10" required>
<button type="button" onclick="generateRandomNumber()">Number Generator</button>
```

Also, you need to read more on [Javascript Functions](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp) and on [Javascript Events](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_events.asp)

Comment: Hi Solar - This answer appears likely to have been written (entirely or partially) by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it, as [posting of AI-generated content is banned here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was AI-generated, please leave feedback accordingly.